# Reverse NSTimer for scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have **NSTimer** and *Action* for it. But I want to call *Action* after 5s for first time, 4s for second time and ... .

```
_timepast = 6;
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(handleDelay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)handleDelay
{
   _timepast = _timepast - 1;
   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(_timepast * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self handleTimer];
   });
}
```

Comment: So it means you want reverse timer, right?

Comment: @HardikShah yea that's right.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to start action after 5 sec and then create first timer which trigger after 5 sec delay and then invalidate first timer and start your second timer with countDown of 5. It means after 5 sec delay you will your selector called and handle action in it. I am giving you code for how second timer works. I hope you will know how to handle first timer for 5 sec delay.

1. Create 2 variable

   `var timerCount = 5`

   `var timer : Timer!`
2. Create timer of 1 sec interval

   `timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target:self, selector: #selector(self.startTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`
3. In the selector method write reverse checking like,

   `func startTimer() {
       if timerCount > 0 {
           label.text = String(timerCount--)
       }
       else {
           timer.invalidate()
       }
    }`

Comment: It doesn't work .. I want my first action call after 5 second, next action after 4, next after 3 and next ones all after .5 second. your code call actions after same time for all.